# Rails4 routing: Is it possible to use permalinks or parameters directly under root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, wildcard, root, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting

```
get ":site_name", to: 'public_site#index'
```

hoping that

```
get("/catsfrommars").should route_to("public_site#index")
```

Unfortunately I am getting the :site_name routed as an action:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"public_site", :action=>"/catsfrommars"}
```

I also tried

```
get "/:site_name", to: 'public_site#index' 
get "(:site_name)", to: 'public_site#index'
```

And the :site_name parameter still gets routed as an action on the specified controller.

Any ideas on how to fix this and get :site_name as a parameter?

Edit: I am trying to do something similar to this: [Rails Routing Question: Mapping Slugs/Permalinks Directly under Root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049455/rails-routing-question-mapping-slugs-permalinks-directly-under-root?rq=1) but with Rails4 syntax. Once I get it working, I'll use constraints to isolate the namespaced app routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route works properly, the issue was with rSpec.

```
{get: "/catsfrommars"}.should route_to(controller: "public_site", 
     action: "index", site_name: "catsfrommars")
```

resolved it, and more specifically moving the get into a block.